# BACKUP LOG cannot be performed because there is no current database backup. Define Current?

Tags: sql-server, backup, transaction-log

I know what the message is telling me; but I am not sure on the definition of "Current" is, I have a Database backup that was performed at 3am on the previous day, that backup resides on a different network folder than my current folder.

I try Backup Log

```
BACKUP LOG MyDatabaseLog TO DISK= @LogFileName WITH INIT;
```

Do I really need to do this immediately before the LOG backup

```
BACKUP DataBase MyDatabase TO DISK= @DBFileName WITH INIT;
```

Or can I specify where the DB backup file is?

P.S. Another process within the group makes the current backups?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know what the message is telling me; but I am not sure on the definition of "Current" is [...]

It generally means there is no full backup (differential base) for the database that was run without the copy_only option.

> [...] I have a Database backup that was performed at 3am on the previous day, that backup resides on a different network folder than my current folder.

Copy_only full backups do not set or change the differential base and cannot be used as a basis for log backups. Make sure it's not a copy_only backup that was taken.

> Or can I specify where the DB backup file is?

No, this data is saved as part of the database metadata which is used to make the decision.